# Flagging (or marking) questions for your own purposes

Tags: support, flags, bounties, unanswered-questions

I want to start offering bounties on a stack that I no longer visit regularly. It has been suggested that I go through unanswered questions looking for good questions that I find interesting and are, perhaps, worth bringing onto the front page by offering a bounty. My problem is that I need to mark questions that I have already considered and have rejected, so that I don't need to look at them again. Is there any convenient way that I can mark or flag questions for my own purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not use the favourite button.  Question that you have viewed will have a different shade of blue(for the title) as those you have never visited.

Comment: Sounds promising, but I'm not seeing any difference on SO. I do for SE stacks, but it's on SO that I need the facility.

Comment: Oh okay... sorry for that.  You didn’t mention it was SO.  Perhaps then you could downvote the question?  If you have downvoted, you immediately go to another question.

Comment: Sorry. You meant the link text. Of course!

Comment: I'll use the link highlighting. There's already enough down-voting on SO. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the Favourite feature (the star under the vote buttons) for this purpose. If you already have any favourites, you can probably bookmark them in your browser and unfavourite them first. You can find a list of your favourites in your [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites).

Comment: Good idea! I don't use favourites. Is there any way that I can modify my search to show only questions that I have not flagged?

Comment: Eh ... no. You can search *in* your favourites with the `infavorites:mine` option, but AFAIK there's no option to exclude them.

Comment: Blast! That means that I still have to look at each question to see if I've starred it. Another problem that I have is that, being in my 60's, my memory isn't that good, hence the reason for my question.